# java logic with flutter ui

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have written a huge java programm (about 6000 lines of code including UI) with javaFX. I decided to convert this project to a flutter project to be cross-platform and make it look nicer. My idea was, that I could just use my Java logic in the flutter project, which actually works pretty easy via MethodChannels in the android directory of a flutter App, but here is my question:

Does this android directory in the flutter project make the project only viable for android (as long as I dont make a similar version for iOS)?

Is there any other way to use my android code other than this android directory (maybe in the normal lib directory)?

Edit: Reworked my questions to make clarify what I was asking for

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: JavaFX is cross platform too (see Gluon mobile) and I doubt that just switching to a different tool chain would automatically make your application look nicer.